# jsoncpp is slow to after updating iOS deployment target from 6.0 to 7.0

Tags: c++, ios, jsoncpp

I'm using jsoncpp to handle JSON parsing of external files in my iOS app.  I recently changed the deployment target from 6.0 to 7.0 and now notice that when the JSON files are loaded and parsed the system takes about 5 seconds longer.  I've put print statements to narrow down the bottleneck to where the JSON library handles looking up the key values.

Has anyone come across this problem and knows a fix for it?

Much appreciated!